# Initialize data in node.js application automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can i initialize the database (add the config data and the admin user automatically) when i run my node.js application for the first time

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve this. A nice way is to use an ORM, like TypeORM or Sequelize. With them, you're supposed to create and run seeds for your app. Here is nice docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#running-seeds

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I use a wrapper to execute the database seeding.
This solution uses only `mongodb` native lib.
To achieve that create a folder named `seeds`.

Inside that folder just create a new js file for seed the mongodb `user` collection inside database `MONGODATABASENAME`.

**seed/seedUser.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const crypto = require('crypto');
const url = `${process.env.MONGOHOST}:${process.env.MONGOPORT}`

MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }
    console.log('Seeding database');
    const password = '#@!thisismysupersecureadminpasswordanditshouldbekeepinsecret!@#'
    crypto.scrypt(password, 'salt', parseInt(process.env.SCRYPTPARAM), (err, derivedKey) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        const user = { name: 'me', login: 'admin', password: derivedKey.toString('hex') }
        const dbinstance = client.db(process.env.MONGODATABASENAME);
        dbinstance.collection('user').insertOne(user).then((result) => {
            console.log(result.insertedId)
            client.close()
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            client.close()
        })
    });
});
```

In my code I'm using the native nodejs lib to hash the password, [here is the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback).
After create this seed js file, you should create a new command in your `scripts` section from `package.json`.

Here the code uses `crypto` module, it comes comes bundled with nodejs.

**package.json**

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "seeddb": "node ./seed/seedUser.js",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
...
}
```

Now if you need seed database, you just run the command:

`$npm run seeddb`